# Get Tasks completed by a user(past tasks information)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to see the tasks handled by a particular user say 'xyz'.
I see that Tasks API provide only the count of completed tasks, However I couldn't find the task details.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Tasks are somewhat ephemeral within TaskRouter. [The documentation says](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/tasks):

> Important: Tasks are **deleted 5 minutes after either they are canceled or completed**. You can still query events that occurred for a Task via the Events API.

You can query against past tasks using the [Events API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/events).

The documentation does also say that if deleting tasks breaks your usecase then do please [get in touch with support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with what you are trying to achieve.

Let me know if that helps at all.